# Number of different tournaments.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

What is the number of different tournaments on $n$ number of teams? Is there any trick or formulation available? 
Tournament: A complete oriented graph, i.e., a graph in which every pair of nodes is connected by a single uniquely directed edge.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)

Comment: @bof 12: You are right. I am interested to find only the nonisomorphic tournaments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of nonisomorphic tournaments on $n$ vertices is given by [OEIS sequence A000518](https://oeis.org/A000568).
The first few terms (from $n=0$ to $n=17$) are
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 12, 56, 456, 6880, 191536, 9733056, 903753248, 154108311168, 48542114686912, 28401423719122304, 31021002160355166848, 63530415842308265100288, 244912778438520759443245824.$$